# How to add custom text to price or How to display EMI prices in order review?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, orders, price, onepage-checkout

As my site uses EMI options for payment the prices in Order review section should be shown in

> Rs.xxx per month

format.

I've made changes to phtml files only [to do this], because it should only be shown like that but price calculations should happen as it is.

Now my problem is, I've used **FlyWebdesign_PaypalFee** extension to add payment method charges, I need to display the payment method charge in the above mentioned format.

[image]

> the prices in the image may not be correct, it's just the format I
>   want. I want Payment charge to be shown as 120 per month

I don't know how to do this, can anyone help please?

I know the payment charge is passed like

```
$address->addTotal(array(
            'code' => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Charge'),
            'full_info' => array(),
            'value' => $amount,
            'emi'   => 'per month' // custom line to show per month.
        ));
```

and i can add an extra element in the array, to fetch it in payment review. But how to appended it to **Rs120.00**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
            $address->addTotal(array(
            'code' => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Charge'),
            'full_info' => array(),
            'value' => $amount,
            'text'  => $appendText // text to be appended
        ));
```

in app/code/local/FlyWebdesign/PaypalFee/Model/Sales/Quote/Address/Total/Paymentcharge.php fetch() method and

```
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getTotal()->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
    <?php if ($this->getRenderingArea() == $this->getTotal()->getArea()): ?><strong><?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()) ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getText(); // print text to be appended ?>
    <?php if ($this->getRenderingArea() == $this->getTotal()->getArea()): ?></strong><?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

in app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/template/checkout/total/**default.phtml**

That does the trick!

Comment: this can be done with 'full_info' parameter, you need to echo $this->getTotal()->getFullInfo(0);